# How can I form a direct URL to sign-in to Gmail's "use another account"

Tags: gmail

I'd like my walk-in shop customer's that use the kiosk computer to see a simple, clean page with Gmail's sign-in page, without having to scroll down all the other customers' accounts until they notice the "use another account" link. (I've seen some are having trouble figuring it out)

I've tried to use this:

> https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/identifier

instead of this:

> https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/signinchooser

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

It does not matter if we'll use a bookmark or a desktop icon, as long as it works. We're running the kiosk on Windows 10, browser is latest version of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to do that.

If you are using Chrome, instead of using a regular Google Chrome profile, use it in guest mode. For details see [Browse Chrome as a guest](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6130773?hl=en).

Other browsers might have a similar feature.

Another option is to use Chrome in incognito mode.

One more option is to clear the cookies after your customers end what they have to do your shop's computer.

Yet another option is to use a software to remotely clear the temporal session  files, let say that from a computer or mobile device use the shop clerk.

Comment: Removing cookies and incognito is an option, but it will not tend to the repetitive customers' needs.. I take it that your first sentence is - there is *no* way to do it?

Comment: you are right... thanks.

Comment: You might have to add more details to the question, specially how the "url" will be used, as will it be added to web browser bookmark or a desktop icon / direct access. Including the OS, and web browser name an version might also be helpful.

Comment: Bookmark or desktop icon, doesn't really matter, whatever works... the computer runs on Windows 10, browser is Chrome latest version.

Comment: @Amos please add those details to the question.